# Task.Factory.StartNew thowing exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Task.Factory.StartNew to make the long processing service calls off the UI thread.However, i am getting the follwing exception as soon as i load the application,

A task's exception were not observed either by waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result the unhandled exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.InitializeViewModel(myViewModel));

private void InitializeViewModel(IModel myViewModel)
{
    lock (viewModelLock)
    {
        myViewModel.MyContext = this.MyContext; // this will set the MyContext property which in turn makes some service calss
    }
}
```

here i can't use task.wait() b'coz then it will cause the wait on the UI thread..

how can i avoid this exception??

Thanks.

Comment: Where is that call to `Task.Factory.StartNew` located?

Comment: You should look at the `InnerExcpetion` of that exception and fix it, not try to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a first workaround/debugging-help wrap your `lock (...)` inside a `try-catch` and set a breakpoint inside the `catch`-Block - this way you should be able to see the problem

To the problem with the `Task.Wait` - you can use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx) method to get the exceptions:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.InitializeViewModel(myViewModel));
task.ContinueWith(o => MyErrorHandler(task.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

don't forget the handler:

```
void MyErrorHandler(Exception error)
{
 // handle the exception (log, or whatever)
}
```

Comment: I am using the ContinueWith and it is not throwing the error , is it the proper way of handling it, or should i write somethong that does not throw exception..please guide

Comment: I use something like this to log unexpected errors and yes I think this is one way to handle this proper - but of course you should write your code to handle errors